# How to build <scp:price unit='USD'>25</scp:price> in Nokogiri XML Builder

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I need some help to build this line in xml. For google content api

Outcome I'm trying to get is `<scp:price unit='USD'>25</scp:price>`

At the moment my code output this line `<scp:price unit='USD'>25</scp:price unit='USD'>` which is incorrect.

Here is my code

```
b = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml.send("scp:price unit='USD'",'25') 
end
```

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that Nokogiri is interpreting the whole `scp:price unit='USD'` as the tag name. You should get better results if you separate the tag name from the attributes:

```
xml.send('scp:price', { :unit => 'USD' }, 25)
```

That should give you the `<scp:price unit="USD">25</scp:price>` that you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Mu is correct, but here's what that's really supposed to look like:

```
b = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root('xmlns:scp' => 'http://scp.com/') do
    xml['scp'].price '25', :unit => 'USD'
  end
end
```